# I need Help making a three-way pivot table in Laravel and showing the output

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I have an app in which I need to ask a series of questions to a group of users.

I have three modals Question | User | Group
A Group has many Questions and a User belongs to many groups

Here are my models

Question:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    public function answer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer')->latest();
    }

    public function userAnswer(){
      return $this->hasOne('App\Answer')->where('user_id', Auth()->id())->latest()->first();
    }
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }

}
```

User:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
      'name', 'email', 'password','district','area','committee','position',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function answer(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimesamps();
    }

    public function assignRole($role)
    {
      $this->roles()->save($role);
    }

    public function abilities()
    {
      return $this->roles->map->abilities->flatten()->pluck('name')->unique();
    }

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }

}
```

Group:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
  public function question()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
  }
}
```

How can I make a pivot table to be able to link an added question to a specific group?

Comment: question belongs to many groups

Comment: Sorry so if users have many groups than relation with question will be same as with user that is the right choice

Comment: question belong to many groups and user belong to only one group

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make a pivot table to be able to link an added question to a specific group?

Since you made many to many relations you should create a separate pivot table `group_question` with fields `group_id` and `question_id`

Than in model to attach question you save it like that:

```
$question->groups()->attach($groupId);
```

And same but `detach` when you want to delete question from group or groups! Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)